# Heroku + PHP + SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, развертывание, heroku

Как настроить SQLite для приложения развернутого на Heroku?

Comment: Ну вы юморист, мсье. В курсе же, что как только dyno уснёт, его файловая система улетит вникуда вместе с базой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-хорошему, **никак**. SQLite ведь не сервер, доступный по сети, а библиотека для работы с неким доступным локально файлом.

Heroku, классическое 12-факторное облако, оперирует **эфемерными файловыми системами**. Облако оставляет за собой право пересоздавать файловую систему время от времени и ваш файл с базой данных SQLite, таким образом, будет периодически пропадать. Вместе со всеми данными.

Сделано это затем, чтобы приложение было проще масштабировать: чтобы можно было запросто поднять ещё одну копию вашего приложения, подключить к тем же базам данных через сеть и... почти удвоить число параллельно обслуживаемых запросов. Вот только когда к SQLite начинаются обращения более чем от одного клиента, начинается светопредставление.

**Так что у вас нелёгкий выбор: либо отказаться от *SQLite*, либо отказаться от *Heroku*.**

---

*...или каким-то образом заставить приложение хранить файл базы во внешнем хранилище, но поднять нормальную РСУБД с доступом по сети может быть даже проще.*